# align text, div and 2 other divs horizontally

Tags: css, css-float

What i have :

```
 <div id="outerDiv" style="margin: 20px;">
                      <div id="innerDiv" style="float: left;">
                          <span>10002</span>

                          <div class="arrow-up" alt='some text' />
                          </br>
                            <div class="arrow-down"/>
                      </div>
                      <div><h3>Text</h3></div>
                      </br>
                      <span>Some plain text
            <br />
                      </span>
                  </div>
```

All elements in outerdiv except span with plain text have to be aligned, and floated to the left, but i cant figure out a way how to do it. if i move something everything else start flying all over the page. What will be the correct way of doing it? Attached a image of what i want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this stracture it can help u

```
    <div id="outerDiv" style="margin: 20px;">
      <div id="innerDiv" style="float: left;">
        <span style="float:left; margin-top:15px;">10002</span>
        <div class=" " style="float:left;">
            <div class="arrow-up" alt='some text' /></div>
            <div class="arrow-down"/></div>
        </div>
        <h3 style="float:left;">Text</h3>
<div style="float:none; clear:both"></div>
      </div>  
      </br>
      <span>Some plain text</span>
    </div>
```